# MongoDB and Node.js query a random value with weight probability

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I am making a game and with item stored in my database, I was thinking about storing them with a weight so that there is xx% chance to get the item.

Is there a way to do that with MongoDB or any alternative considering the database is not filled yet, I wasn't able to find anything on Google

I'm using Node.js for the code part and I CAN do stuff on the code part like generating random number or so if needed

I was thinking about just generating a random number between 0 and 1 do a inferior or equal check with the weight and pick a document randomly, so that the higher the weight the less likely it's looted, would this be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Create a collection
2. Scale the probability to an integer value (e.g. 0-100)
3. For each document, insert into the new collection X documents where X is the probability of the original document. The only field needed in the new collection is the id of the original document, but since _id must be unique you'd need to store the id value in some other field
4. Use $sample to get a weighted random document id from the new collection
5. Look up the document via its id in the original collection (as a separate query or via $lookup)

Comment: It sounds like a good idea but it also looks like a "cheat" rather than a clean solution, I might do this if I don't find any better solution though. Thanks for your answer